# Rendirá SQLite para un CMS web?

Tags: php, sqlite

Buenas estoy aprendiendo un poco sobre SQLite (ya manejo lo que respecta a consultas y aún estoy viendo varios detalles respecto a seguridad y demás), y estaba pensando armar un pequeño CMS (para landing pages)

Y... convendría esto? Que tanta diferencia habría con MySQL a la hora de la práctica/uso?

El concepto es un backend exclusivamente para cambiar el contenido y rutas a enlaces/imágenes y ya...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En realidad depende del CMS y qué quiere hacer con él. Si es para solo lectura como mencionas no creo que haya problemas pero si los enlaces y rutas a imágenes van a registrarse continuamente puede no ser conveniente, aquí te dejo algunas ventajas/desventajas para que puedas analizar mejor:

**Ventajas:**

- Alta portabilidad (no sé de qué serviría en un CMS eso)
- Soporta tráfico bajo/alto (en el website oficial incluso mencionan que lo usan y soporta 500k request al website con un uso de la bd de 15 a 20%)

**Desventajas:**

- Lentitud progresiva en querys al crecer. No maneja archivos de configuración para performance.
- Limitación en consultas con where.
- Solo un proceso puede escribir a la vez, y al hacerlo bloquea toda la tabla por lo que no es apto para aplicaciones distribuidas que además tengan que manipular mucha data.
- Aplicación y BD deben estar en la misma máquina.

Espero te sirva para evaluar y elegir.

Fuente: 
http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html

Comment: Caso hipotético: Me solicitan un sitio web con 4 páginas/internas, todo el contenido estaría en la dB, y el backend consistiría exclusivamente para poder cambiar las imágenes (del slider y otras áreas) y el texto que tendrá cada página/interna del sitio...

Por lo que sería puro SELECTs para los contenidos todo el tiempo y cada que el cliente quiera cambiar la imágen, agregar o borrar un poco de texto, UPDATE...


por aquí radicaría mi idea para un pequeño "CMS" hecho con SQLite

Comment: @KuroNeko, bajo ese enfoque no habría ningún problema. Pero dime, qué te mueve a querer hacerlo en SQLite y no en MySQL? es por experimentación o es por alguna ventaja de SQLite de las expuestas?

Comment: Principalmente va por el lado de la experimentación, además que precisará solamente Apache/PHP para poder funcionar, por lo que si en algun momento cae el servicio de MySQL (cosa que suelo ver bastante en servidores compartidos), no le afectará ello. Además que será copypastear un archivo y BackUp listo...

Comment: Es cierto que tiene esas ventajas y genial que sea experimentación. Ya solo queda en ti evaluar beneficios vs. desventajas. Buena suerte!